# THC-IPV6 Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux, ipv6

After I have upgraded to Kali Linux Sana I have noticed that the THC-IPV6 kit ,with tools such as flood_router26, has disappeared. If somebody could tell me where it is, or how to install it again, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The THC-IPv6 tools are still there:

```
# locate alive6
/usr/bin/atk6-alive6
/usr/bin/atk6-inject_alive6
...
# locate flood_router26
/usr/bin/atk6-flood_router26
...
```

Moreover, the source code for the tools is avalible on [github](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-ipv6)